# Filter list with whereIn condition in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, filter, flutter-hive

This code sample works fine.

```
var box = await Hive.openBox<MainWords>('mainWords');
box.values.where((item)  {
      return item.category == "6" || item.category == '13';
    }).toList();
```

I am trying to filter a list with whereIn condition but it must filter like

```
List<String> categoryList = ['6', '13'];
var box = await Hive.openBox<MainWords>('mainWords');
box.values.where((item)  {
      return item in categoryList; // just an examle
    }).toList();
```

How can i achive this?

Comment: Maybe ```categoryList.contains(item)```?, are you trying to filter the values based on ```categoryList```?. Please clarify what you trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use the keyword `in` but the method `contains` to check if your `item` exists inside `categoryList`. Moreover you cannot compare values of different types, I'm seeing that you are returning with `box.values` an `Iterable<MainWords>`.

I don't know the content of this class but the `item` variable is of type `MainWords` and so it cannot be compared with a `String` object directly.

I am supposing that you have some access to a `String` value from your class `MainWords` so you will need to compare this value with your list.

**Code Sample**

```dart
List<String> categoryList = ['6', '13'];
var box = await Hive.openBox<MainWords>('mainWords');

// As I don't know what are MainWords' properties I named it stringValue.
box.values.where((item) => categoryList.contains(item.stringValue)).toList();
```